# Reference or find unidentified parent element from within that element

Tags: javascript, get, src

If this question cannot be answered, then I'm going to post a second, "fall back" question.
I have been writing javascript jsonp type apps where the client has to insert a single javascript line into wherever they want the app to show up on the web page. So far it's work out pretty well, but now I want to add one more GET variable to the js src attribute, and that is the present client's page url.

before:

```
<script id="myScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/scripts/ds.js?cid=00000001&domain=clientdomain.com"></script>
```

But now for the new twist, I want to add the page url as a GET variable in the src, like so:

```
<script id="myScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/scripts/ds.js?cid=00000001&domain=clientdomain.com&page="+document.URL></script>
```

If document.URL is placed between the script tag, I can do it (but that leads me to have to write a slightly larger and less elegant code block). Maybe javascript is not actually allowed in the attribute parameters of the tag, itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do something like this is to build the tag itself in JavaScript. You can get an added benefit of asynchronous loading (although this can be a problem if you don't know how to handle asynchronous loading properly). For example:

```
<script>
    (function(d){
        var f=d.createElement('script'),s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        f.type='text/javascript';
        f.async=true;
        f.src='http://www.mydomain.com/scripts/ds.js?cid=00000001&domain=clientdomain.com&page='+encodeURI(document.location.href);
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(f,s)
    })(document)
</script>
```

Google Analytics uses similar code so you're in good company. And you're quite right that you can't do this directly inside a HTML tag.

Comment: Also notice that I added `encodeURI`. Without that you could get some bizarre issues.

Comment: Hmmm...let me give that a try. Of course, that means writing a "chunk" of code, rather than inserting a single script tag. But, it could be what I'm after isn't really possible. Yes, Google Analytics, AdSense, and even the Facebook Like button are "chunks" rather than single tag insertions. I guess I should take my cues from them. I just thought I might be able to break new ground by reducing it even further.

Comment: @GregoryLewis I wouldn't try to "break new ground" in JavaScript syntax. Google made a new browser to break new ground, but still they use this method (mainly because it's not something that needs fixing).

Comment: Well, I think the answer by Dave actually improves what I'm after in a way I hadn't anticipated (the finding of an unknown parentNode, and inserting into it), pre-empting my "fallback" question. So I'm going to mark it as "Correct Answer". Thanks, Dave!